# Multiple threads are not working simultaneously on Ubuntu in C

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu

I have written a code using `multi-threading` which creates two `threads`.

- `Consumer Thread`: To `dequeue` one element from a `Circular Queue`.
- `Producer Thread`: To `enqueue` ten elements in the `Circular Queue`.

`Consumer Thread` is in waiting state before insertion of six elements and only works i.e. `dequeue` element after `Producer Thread` inserts six elements in the `queue`.Following is my Code:

```
void *producer(void *t)
{
  int i;
  long my_id = (long)t;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) 
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    printf("\nInserting value = %d ",count);
    enQueue(count);
    displayQueue();
    count++;
    if (count == 6)
    {
      pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
      printf("\nproducer: thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n",my_id, count);
    }
    printf("\nproducer: thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n",my_id, count);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *consumer(void *t)
{
  long my_id = (long)t;
  printf("Starting Consumer Thread(): thread %ld\n", my_id);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
  while (count<6) 
  {
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
    printf("\nconsumer: thread %ld Condition signal received.\n", my_id);
  }
  printf(" \nDeleted value =%d ",deQueue());
  displayQueue();
  printf("\nconsumer: thread %ld count now = %d.\n", my_id, count);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, rc;
  long t1=1, t2=2;
  pthread_t threads[2];
  //Threads Created

  pthread_create(&threads[1], &attr, consumer, (void *)t1);
  pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, producer, (void *)t2);

 //Thread Clean Up Followed
}
```

The code is working as expected in `Windows(CodeBlocks)`.

- 0-5 inserted in queue first
- On inserting 6, Threshold reached and one element removed from `queue`.
- After this, 6-9 inserted in `queue`.

But when executed in `Ubuntu` the, First 0-9 elements are inserted then one element is removed from `queue`.
Command for compiling in `ubuntu`: `g++ -pthread name.cpp`.
What is the reason for this different behavior and how to fix this?
For entire code [Follow link](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/FXJFqn)

Comment: There is way too much code here. Can this be reduced to a [mcve]

Comment: I had added  the entire program so that entire functionality could be checked.It is a bug free program.Although the main functionality is implemented in `Producer` and `Consumer` functions only, but since the problem is  in execution in ubuntu, I had added entire code so that it could be checked and executed in ubuntu. Now I have removed extra code for your convenience.

Comment: now it is not a working example... You have to add again some or the code so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: @koleygr I have added link for entire code [Here](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/FXJFqn). Try this in your own IDE.

Comment: With all due respect, this is C.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. There is nothing in the producer that makes it wait for anything. Why would you expect things to happen in any particular order?

Comment: @Art I need a specific order and synchronization for my functionality. In my actual scenario producer and consumer are working with different speeds due to some extra functions in consumer.So to fix them I need this implementation.

Comment: You have 2 threads here,  Your producer thread could start, insert an element or 2, then the consumer thread could start and reach the `while (count<6) ` part and pick out an item before you reach 6 items.

Comment: @nos Actual flow of program should be : Started Consumer Thread first. Consumer waits while count is less than 6. While waiting Producer starts. When count gets equal to 6 , it signals to finish the wait and resume consumer.Consumer resumes and removes an element. Consumer thread exits. Producer Thread resumes to insert rest of the elements. Producer exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the reason for this different behavior

Threads don't give you any guarantees that things in two different threads will happen in any particular order unless you explicitly synchronize so that they do. You don't synchronize, so things happen in some order, then they happen in a different order. This is totally expected.

If you want things to happen in exactly some order you either have to explicitly make both threads wait for each other or don't use threads.

As your code is right now there is nothing that prevents "producer" from looping 10 times and then exiting.

Comment: There is something that prevents `producer` from looping 10 times: The signal command when `count==6`. It signals the consumer thread to resume functionality halted by `wait` statement. Also this is working in Windows correctly.In Windows, when the `count==6` the consumer thread executes to `dequeue` an element.But in Ubuntu, Consumer thread dequeues  in last i.e after termination of producer.

Comment: @HimanshuJindal You are assuming your consumer thread gets to execute `pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);` before the producer thread inserts any items - but nothing in your code prevents that from happening - so you might very well see differences in behavior on 2 different operating systems. Also note that `printf("\nInserting value = %d ",count);` will trick you, if you run the program in a terminal, you'll not see that output immediately. Add \n at the end.

Comment: @HimanshuJindal Calling `pthread_cond_signal` does not stop the calling thread. It will wake up the thread that's in `pthread_cond_wait`, but there is nothing anywhere that says that this should prevent the caller from keeping running. And there's nothing that says when the consumer should start running.

Comment: In fact, I don't even see anything in here that guarantees that the consumer thread has even started running any code before producer has queued everything and exited.

Comment: got your point @Art . This is one of the possibility and this kind of behavior can be OS dependent. Any idea how to fix this??

Comment: @nos Consumer is executing `pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex)` before producer starts inserting.I have checked it by printing something before wait statement.

Comment: To get the behavior you want , you'll need 2 condition variables then. The producer needs to wait on the 2. condition variable after it inserted 6 elements, the consumer needs to wake up the producer again when it consumed all 6 elements through that condition

Answer (score -1):

There are situations that create dead lock in your code. As an example if the 'consumer' Thread started before the 'producer' thread it create the dead lock situation. The 'consumer' is waiting to signal 'count_threshold_cv' and it already acquired the 'count_mutex' mutex. Mean time the 'producer' is waiting to acquire 'count_mutex'. So this dead lock situation causes the application to hang. Please design application to avoid such. We cannot guaranteed which thread starts first. Specially acquiring mutex should be don only for required set of code segment.

Edit: Since 'pthread_cond_wait' pass 'count_mutex' this does not create dead lock. But since we cannot guaranteed the order of thread execution the behavior is unpredictable.
Further you cannot rely on the cout out put. Since the out put might not grantees to be in the order of execution.

Comment: If deadlock had occurred at that point in consumer thread, Producer would not have executed.But threads are working after the deadlock also. This means when we signaled `wait` command, the `mutex` is unlocked for the waiting time. I have also read the same on some document.Also don't forget the code is working correctly on Windows.

Comment: If the 'consumer' starts first, The dead lock might not happened. So based on situation ... it may run on windows.

Comment: not getting your point. I have executed same code in both windows and ubuntu.I have not modified anything while executing in ubuntu.

Comment: The Art's reply explain this more.

Comment: @Pra That is not a deadlock. When you perform `pthread_cond_wait` , the mutex gets unlocked (and locked again before `pthread_cond_wait` returns)

Comment: Sorry. It is my mistake. I didn't pay attention to that part. Thank you very much for information.